react-paypal-js create subscription return an error
I am using @paypal/react-paypal-js library for paypal recurring payment.
I have created Product as well as Subscription plan
my code is below
                       <PayPalScriptProvider
                          options={{
                            "client-id": `${process.env.REACT_APP_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID}`,
                            vault: true,
                            intent: "subscription"
                          }}
                        >
                          <PayPalButtons
                            style={{
                              shape: "rect",
                              color: "gold",
                              layout: "vertical",
                              label: "subscribe"
                            }}
                            createSubscription={(data, actions) => {
                              return actions.subscription.create({
                                /* Creates the subscription */
                                plan_id: "PLAN-ID"
                              });
                            }}
                            onApprove={(data, actions) => {
                              console.log(data);
                              console.log(actions);
                            }}
                            onError={(data) => {
                              console.log(data);
                            }}
                          />
                        </PayPalScriptProvider>

and when i am loggedin with sandbox personal account its returning below error


can you please help me how to solved this error

what is the PLAN-ID, how was it created

i have tried both way, 1. created by UI 2. created by API

The UI way won't work unless you use the resulting client ID as REACT_APP_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID.  The API way should work, update your question with the API request and API response of plan creation
